# Absolute Value of the DFT with OpenCV in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to compute the DFT in C++ with OpenCV. I want the absolute value of the DFT. To compute it I do:

```cpp
vector<float> areas, X_mag; 
cv::Mat X;

...

cv::dft(areas, X, cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
```

areas is a 50x1 vector, and I want to store the absolute value of the DFT of areas in X_mag

The problem, is that I think there is no way to compute directly the absolute value, and I didn't find any function that computes directly the absolute.

I tried to use [absdiff](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga6fef31bc8c4071cbc114a758a2b79c14): `cv::absdiff(X, cv::Scalar::all(0), X_mag);`, but it only works if I use a std::vector instead of the cv::Mat.

If I don't use the DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT, I get only the real part, so is not what I need.

I was thinking on computing manually the absolute value (sqrt(Re(X)^2 + Im(X)^2), but I think it would be too slow, and I don't think that cv::Mat was thought to be iterated this way.

How could I get my 50x1 DFT's absolute value vector?

Comment: `cv::split` to get real and imaginary "plane", then `cv::magnitude`? perhaps some stuff from this article could help you https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d01/tutorial_discrete_fourier_transform.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Christoph Rackwitz said, we can use [split](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga0547c7fed86152d7e9d0096029c8518a) and [magnitude](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga6d3b097586bca4409873d64a90fe64c3).

```
vector<float> areas, X_abs;
Mat X;
Mat X_mag[2];

...

cv::dft(areas, X, cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
cv::split(X, X_mag);
cv::magnitude(X_mag[0], X_mag[1], X_abs);
```

And we will have the absolute value vector in X_abs.